# How to load a custom view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a new project with storyboard, I wanted to load a custom view (no xib) in the uiviewcontroller, I referenced [Creating a View Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html), but it doesn't work. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding,i think you are trying to load a custom view with out xib file in storyboard.
Here is the sample code for [moving the screen one to two and showing the views.](http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/39343130/file.html)

Comment: Almost,but i'm trying to load a custom view without xib file in storyboard when it load view,not button clicking event.